# Python35: csv.writer how not to skip rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def writetocsv(l):
 #convert the set to the list
 b = list(l)
 print (b)
 with open("eggs.csv",'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for value in b:
             w.writerow([value])

url = 'http://espn.go.com/nhl/teams'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
hockey_teams = []

for l in soup.findAll("a",{"class":"bi"}):
        hockey_teams.append(l.get_text())
writetocsv(hockey_teams)
```

and its printing like this:
1 Chicago Blackhawks
2 
3 Colorado Avalanche
how can I make it not to skip the rows...?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
with open("nhlteams.csv",'w',newline='',) as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
```

it was in newline= " " it was required to make it not skip